# Inserting reCaptcha to Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, recaptcha

I'll try to keep shis short. I was asked to add captcha to some forms on one of our websites. These sites are very old. Still using tables. Anyways, the forms they want me to modify are using CFM pages. I know next to nothing about CFM, but the site pretty much relies on CFM to pull or generate info, sometimes parts being reused as displaying menus and etc.

Anyways, I wasn't sure what would be the best way or easier to insert the reCaptcha. I tried using the no plugin version. It would display the captcha and would let me know if I needed a proper email address or what not, but I don't think it was verifying the captcha itself. just the Javascript in the action page. Plus I coudn't figure out where the private key info needed to be inserted. The instructions seem very vague on this.

Now I'm trying the CFM tag mentioned by Sean Coyne (updated version). But I'm still having issues. Whenever I add the CFM tags into the pages I get an internal server error page. My Dreamweaver also says there's an error on line 200, not sure if it's significant but no matter what I've tried nothing has worked for me.

The error is from the CFM tag on line 200. It says it's a syntax error but I don't know what the exact problem of it is. Link to CFM tag: https://gist.github.com/2210356

`<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme:'#jsStringFormat(attributes.theme)#',
        tabindex: #attributes.tabIndex#
    };
    //-->
    </script>`

I'm primarily focusing on getting this all to work for **act_emailFriend3.cfm** **dsp_detailList3.cfm** and **dsp_Details3.cfm**

The other 2 files are for a seperate form that most likely needs updating but is using a different captcha insertion and verification. ( **contact_us.cfm** and **ResultContactUs.cfm** )

I know I'm confused over something that shouldn't be this difficult. I was hoping maybe someone could take a look at the CFM pages and find out what I'm doing wrong or an easier way.

Link to new files I'm working on: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwSit_LQViOGRUttSjNEY0JYa28/edit

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners here.

Comment: What is the error? You mentioned an error on line 200, but unless you let us know the error we can't help.